# datetimes and dates should never be equal

Tags: python

```py
from datetime import datetime, date

class MyDate(date):
    pass

print(MyDate(2024, 3, 8) == datetime(2024, 3, 8))
print(date(2024, 3, 8) == datetime(2024, 3, 8))
```

Expected output:

```py
False
False
```

Actual output:

```py
True
False
```

Why does subclassing `datetime.date` change the `__eq__` result?

Comment: `date.__eq__(date(2024, 3, 8), datetime(2024, 3, 8))` returns `True`

Comment: Also, `date(2024, 3, 8).__eq__(datetime(2024, 3, 8))` is `True`.

Comment: It could be useful as well to know what version of python was used for that experiment.

Comment: @DjaouadNM I think you should undelete your answer. The C implementation works in the same way, but it has the comment that explains this behavior. That's the only difference.

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM Shortly, I was just trying to see why for instance this `date(2024, 3, 8).__eq__(datetime(2024, 3, 8))` returned true, and the fact that it's actually not implemented for `datetime.datetime` yet it returns `False` instead of NotImplemented. But I will update correspondingly.

Answer (score 5):

Looking at the Python source code for [`datetime.date.__eq__`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/7db871e4fa48eef20ea22414b226998f83facfd6/Lib/_pydatetime.py#L1111) (the fallback implementation), we find the following definition, which does not implement an equality operator between a `datetime.date` object and a `datetime.datetime` object (in that order):

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    if isinstance(other, date) and not isinstance(other, datetime):
        return self._cmp(other) == 0
    return NotImplemented
```

In the example where the result is `False`, the `self` object are instances of `datetime.date`, and are not instances of `datetime.datetime` (satisfying the `if` condition), so they get compared and `__eq__` returns whatever the result of the comparison is.

Similarly, as noted by @Abdul Niyas P M, by looking at the [C implementation of this operator](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/61831585b637eb621bc80ae39e2e59541c135dc5/Modules/_datetimemodule.c#L3486) (which is the default implementation), the definition is equivalent in logic, and further contains comments on this particular behavior:

```
static PyObject *
date_richcompare(PyObject *self, PyObject *other, int op)
{
    /* Since DateTime is a subclass of Date, if the other object is
     * a DateTime, it would compute an equality testing or an ordering
     * based on the date part alone, and we don't want that.
     * So return NotImplemented here in that case.
     * If a subclass wants to change this, it's up to the subclass to do so.
     * The behavior is the same as if Date and DateTime were independent
     * classes.
     */
    if (PyDate_Check(other) && !PyDateTime_Check(other)) {
        int diff = memcmp(((PyDateTime_Date *)self)->data,
                          ((PyDateTime_Date *)other)->data,
                          _PyDateTime_DATE_DATASIZE);
        return diff_to_bool(diff, op);
    }
    else
        Py_RETURN_NOTIMPLEMENTED;
}
```

However, the fact `False` is being returned instead of `NotImplemented` raises another question, but this could be due to the Python version the OP was using when running their code.

For instance, the [3.12.2](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.12.2/Lib/_pydatetime.py#L1113) version source code of the same method (and [C implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.12.2/Modules/_datetimemodule.c#L3441)) does not prevent the comparison when `other` is a `datetime.datetime`:

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    if isinstance(other, date):
        return self._cmp(other) == 0
    return NotImplemented
```

Comment: Python [`datetime` module is a fallback implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2647afeab694517933c53028d4ad427460b9e1fa/Lib/datetime.py#L1-L6). The actual implementation comes [from C](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/7cee276d551a41d9271daf2a6bcd7def55555973/Modules/_datetimemodule.c#L3487-L3504). It has a comment which documents this behaviour.

Comment: this reasoning doesn't make sense- the subclass instance is the "self" here, not the "other".

Comment: @nosteponsnek Yes, that was a mistake, what I meant to say was that the comparison that resulted in `False` is one where self is a date instance (hence its method will be called), and the other is a datetime instance, hence it won't be compared, which actually raises another question for me, about why it is returning False instead of NotImplemented, but this could be due to the Python version you are using not being the current release I got this source code from.

Comment: Also, for some reason `date(2024, 3, 8).__eq__(datetime(2024, 3, 8))` returns `True` as well, which seems inconsistent.

Comment: The issue is not about the result of `False`. The result false is the _expected output_, and don't need to explain this "correct" result. Question asks about the result `True`, which looks incorrect, and this answer doesn't answer that at all.

Comment: @nosteponsnek What Python version are you using?

Comment: The latest version i.e. 3.12.2